# Refer to variables dynamically

Tags: python, django

**Context:** I am creating a Django management command which will accept a positional argument. This argument is a location. My goal is to use the location value to refer to a corresponding variable.

I have a global variable named `Boston_webhook`. This is a simple string which contains a long URL which is just a MSteams webhook...

I have an additional global variable named `Budapest_webhook` which contains the same data type, but instead refers to a webhook related to the Budapest location.

In my script, a connector variable has to be defined in order to send the message to the correct place.

```
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard()
```

If someone entered python manage.py report `Boston` I want to insert this into the connector params, but I am unsure how to refer to variables dynamically.

Is it possible to refer to Boston_webhook when the location == 'Boston' using some sort of concatenation...?

something like `myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard(location + _webhook)` would be ideal

I would like to avoid using conditionals as it is not scalable. I need to be able to add locations to the database without having to change code...

Comment: "I need to be able to add locations to the database without having to change code" then why are you using _global_ variables? They don't seem to suit your use case. Also why not simply use a dictionary to perform this mapping if you want to do things this way?

Comment: In Django you will probably do best defining a model to represent anything that's backed by a database. If it weren't for that database requirement I'd say just use a dict, `webhooks = {"Boston": "someurl", "Budapest": "someotherurl"}` etc, but that's not the best approach when you're pulling in the values from a DB. But Django makes that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dictionary to map names of webhooks to webhooks itself - like this

```
webhooks = {
    "Boston": "boston url",
    "Budapest": "budapest url"
}
```

Now you can refer to your webhooks like this

```
# this will give you Boston webhook
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard(location + webhooks["Boston"])
```

This is simpliest way to do it. I think it would be better to create new class only for this and convert that class to string using a method , but this would be enough if you don't need anything more complex

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine a suitable solution;

`myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard(webhooks["{}".format(location)])`

where the webhooks are stored in a dictionary keyed by location name.
i.e:

```
webhooks = {'Boston':'www.url.com',
            'Budapest':'www.url1.com',
           }
```

Thanks for the recommendations everyone!

Comment: Long term, this will be related to a Django model and the webhooks will be stored in a database. This solution is only temporary as the application is in production. Migrations can only take place during certain periods. This solution will solve our short term problem. Eventually I will be able to implement a new model which this script will then be built off of